# Unexpected behavior of arrow operator "->" in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree

**The code I have provided is simple BST with insert & inorder traversal only.**

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

Node* create(int data){
    Node* node = new Node;
    node -> data = data;
    node->left=node->right=NULL;
    return node; 
}

Node* insert(Node* ptr,int item);
void inorder(Node* ptr);

int main(){
    Node* root = NULL;
    int temp,ch;
    root = insert(root, 10);
    root = insert(root, 20);
    root = insert(root, 30);

    inorder(root);
    cout<<endl;
}

Node* insert(Node* ptr,int item){
    if(ptr==NULL){
        cout<<"Inserted "<<item<<endl;
        return create(item);
    }
    if(item<ptr->data){
        // ptr = ptr->left;
        // ptr = insert(ptr, item)
        ptr->left=insert(ptr->left, item);
    }
    else{
        // ptr=ptr->right;
        // ptr = insert(ptr, item)
        ptr->right=insert(ptr->right, item);
    }
    return ptr;
}

void inorder(Node* ptr){
    if(ptr==NULL)
        return;
    inorder(ptr->left);
    cout<<ptr->data<<" ";
    inorder(ptr->right);
}
```

when I use,

```
ptr = ptr->left;
ptr = insert(ptr, item)
```

instead of

```
ptr->left=insert(ptr->left, item);
```

*The inorder traversal only prints the last inserted element.*

**Please explain if it is problem of c++ or my understanding is wrong about that concept?**

Comment: one is "copy the value of ptr->left to ptr, change ptr" the other is "change ptr->left"

Comment: `ptr` is a local variable. Reassigning it (as per your first version) doesn't affect any other object

Comment: Try stepping through the code with a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ptr->left=insert(ptr->left, item);
```

Will change the content of the `ptr` object. It does the insert and stores it.

However, when you do:

```
ptr = ptr->left;
ptr = insert(ptr, item)
```

you first get a pointer to what `ptr->left` was pointing, you insert in the same way. But the return value doesn't get stored in your **original** `ptr` object.

So, there's nothing strange. The only way I know for you to understand it fully is to draw a tree. Have a box showing the object, and a pointer to it, and for each operation, update your drawing. It should become clear.

Answer (score 2):

Important part of the code is:

```
Node* insert(Node* ptr,int item){
```

For the sake of explanation, consider you call it like this:

```
Node x;
Node* p = &x;
insert(p, 42);
```

Here `p` is passed by value. It is a pointer. If you modify `ptr`, then changes will only apply to the local `ptr` not to `p`.

If however you assign to `ptr->first` then you are modifying the object pointed to by `ptr`. And even though the pointer is passed by value, `ptr` does point to the same object as `p` does. That is: `ptr->first = something;` inside the function does modify a member of `x`.